# Anyone have any experience ordering slabs or wood?

Tags: wood, woodworking

I've been looking around lately for 2 slabs of Oak possibly reclaimed for some bar tops in my house. We live in CO where pine in plentiful but Oak is not. I need something that will be a little more resistant to kids than pine will be. I'm coming up with nothing. Has anyone here had any experience with ordering something like this?

Comment: You might or might not get more/better answers in the Woodworking discussion.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware that there was a wood working forum of this site

Answer (score 1):

Keep your eyes open for newspaper or online notices of Yard Sales & Estate Sales, these will also include Landlords, Stores, Hotels & Casinos looking to get their buildings cleaned out by the public wanting to remove anything.

Constantly check Craigslist types of websites, your phonebook & internet for Auction, Salvage & Reclamation companies & yards. They usually get the best stuff because they're on the call list of Demolition companies.

Finally, check Salvation Army, Goodwill, Green Drop & Habitat For Humanity. And, consider dismantling a large old Bedroom Dresser or Armoire or an old Diningroom Table or maybe a China Cabinet & an old Livingroom Coffee Table.

Comment: Good suggestions. I have been doing just that. I'm just at the point where I need to get something and quick. The pain is I have two countertops so I need large sections of the same type of wood. I found that at some of the more expensive stores like Crate and Barrel there are sales on specific tables where I can buy more than one for a "decent price"

Comment: Oh, you're already at Plan Z & not Plan H. I'd have to go with a Lumber Yard (store) & one of their employees. They'll have long narrow planks of Hickory, Hard Maple, White & Red Oak & Beech that they can help you Book-Match & lay-out dry to see if they're glue ready. if not glue ready, then you'll need a Wood Shop & their Jointer Machine to prep the sides or to do everything (finishing too) with their supplier...referrals from Lumber Yard. For depth, you can go with a much cheaper wood as a backer or filler. But, you'll need screw Slots or Large Holes in that so it can move separately.

Comment: Additionally, you can possibly stomach or go with Butcher Block Counter & Workbench tops that even Online Wal-Mart has. They're not nearly as gorgeous, but they're all hardwood & therefore hold up amazingly.

Comment: Do you have any salvage stores neaby?  In Seattle we have several and a couple of them always have slabs cut from local trees that had to come down.  Another has large old beams and the like.  http://www.seconduse.com

Comment: Not really, the closest might by an hour away. And good luck around me, no-one can even be paid to harvest a tree. Even old furniture in mint condition that served flawlessly for 50-100years is equivalent to anything particle board. Unless it's antique or has some popularity contest label on it, it's literally trash. The masses are donkeys.